# Customize Reactive Search DateRange

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, reactivesearch

How would I tackle the implementation of internationalized ReactiveSearch DateRange component? I need a custom date format ("dd.mm.yyyy") and translated Names of months.

```
<ReactiveBase
  app="carstore-dataset"
  credentials="4HWI27QmA:58c731f7-79ab-4f55-a590-7e15c7e36721">

  <DateRange
    componentId="DateSensor"
    dataField="mtime"
    title="DateRange"
    defaultValue={{
      start: new Date('2019-04-01'),
      end: new Date('2019-04-07')
    }}
    placeholder={{
        start: 'Start Date',
        end: 'End Date'
    }}
    focused={true}
    numberOfMonths={2}
    queryFormat="date"
    autoFocusEnd={true}
    showClear={true}
    showFilter={true}
    filterLabel="Date"
    URLParams={false}
  />

  <div>
    Hello ReactiveSearch!
  </div>
</ReactiveBase>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify please ? Do you want this format in UI to be displayed or do you want this format to be queried with.

Comment: @Yash I want this format in UI. Not format in query. It's impossible unless modify node_module ?

Comment: Did this solve your issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the delay in responding. `DateRange` internally uses `DayPickerInput` from `react-day-picker` and Date Component have a prop called `dayPickerInputProps`  you can directly use it to send props directly to the internal component.

To format the UI Date you will need to use additional package and props. You can go over to this page: https://react-day-picker.js.org/docs/input/ and scroll to section called `Change Date Format` to understand better.

Here is a sample code snippet to format the UI:

**Packages Required:**

```
import dateFnsFormat from "date-fns/format";
import dateFnsParse from "date-fns/parse";
import { DateUtils } from "react-day-picker";
```

**Code**

```
function parseDate(str, format, locale) {
  const parsed = dateFnsParse(str, format, { locale });
  if (DateUtils.isDate(parsed)) {
    return parsed;
  }
  return undefined;
}

function formatDate(date, format, locale) {
  return dateFnsFormat(date, format, { locale });
}

const FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy"; // Your Format

<DateRange
  componentId="DateSensor"
  dayPickerInputProps={{
     formatDate,
     format: FORMAT,
     parseDate
  }}
  dataField="date_from"
/>
```

You can check a working example over here: https://codesandbox.io/s/daterange-9qfvo

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Great thanks, it works perfectly. Can you write some code about internationalizing?

Comment: I don't have experience with internationalizing you can for sure create an issue on ReactiveSearch to get help from others who have already achieved it.